# ¿Para qué sirve ! antes de una variable?

Tags: c++, arduino

Me gustaria que me expliquen para qué sirve un `!` antes de una variable asignada, ejemplo:

```
if( onoffswitchstate != previusonoffswitchstate){
  if(onoffswitchstate == HIGH){
     motorenabled = !motorenabled;
```

Answer (score 8):

El caracter `!` se menciona en el estándar de C++ en el apartado de operadores:

> #### 2.12 Operadores y puntuación
>
> 1. La representación léxica de los programas C++ incluye un número de tokens de preprocesado que se usan en la sintaxis del preprocesador o se convierten en tokens para operadores y puntuación:
>
>    *operador-o-puntuacion uno de*:
>
>    ```
>    {    }  [    ]       #      ##      (     )
>    <:   :>      <%      %>     %:      %:%:  ;       :   ...
>    new  delete  ?       ::     .       .*
>    +    -       *       /      %       ˆ     &       |   ~
>    !    =       <       >      +=      -=    *=      /=  %=
>    ˆ=   &=      |=      <<     >>      >>=   <<=     ==  !=
>    <=   >=      &&      ||     ++      --    ->*     ->
>    and  and_eq  bitand  bitor  compl   not   not_eq
>    or   or_eq   xor     xor_eq
>    ```

Así que le caracter `!` es un operador, si consultamos el apartado de operadores:

> #### 13.6 Operadores incorporados
>
> 23. También existen funciones candidatas aoperador con la forma:
>
>     ```
>     bool operator!(bool);
>     bool operator&&(bool, bool);
>     bool operator||(bool, bool);
>     ```

Lo que nos indica que `!` es un operador unario (que tiene efecto sobre un sólo elemento). Vemos que recibe un booleano como parámetro y su resultado es booleano:

```
//                vvvv <--- Parámetro
   bool operator!(bool);
// ^^^^ <--- Resultado
```

Por lo tanto, cualquier cosa interpretable como booleano será suceptible de ser usada con el operador unario `!`, el resultado será el valor booleano negado:

```
| expresión | resultado |
+-----------+-----------|
|   !true   |   false   |
|   !false  |   true    |
|   !1      |   false   |
|   !0      |   true    |
|   !(1-1)  |   true    |
|   !(1+2)  |   false   |
```

En tu caso:

```
 motorenabled = !motorenabled;
```

La variable `motorenabled` pasará a obtener el valor opuesto al que tuviera anteriormente cada vez que se llame la instrucción anterior.

Answer (score 4):

Bienvenido amaro, el símbolo `!` es una simple negación:

Si tu variable `motorenabled` es igual a `true`, al poner ese símbolo al principio la variable se vuelve false. 
Y también viceversa: si la variable es false entonces se vuelve true.